# If a linear space can be represented as the direct sum of two sets of subspaces, how do I show that the subspaces are equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

I need some help with proving the following.

"Let linear space $X = \oplus_{j}U_{j}$ where ${U_{j}}$ is a set of non-trivial subspaces of $X$. Let subspace $V_{j}$ be such that $X = \oplus_{j}V_{j}$ and that $U_{j} \subset V_{j}$. Show that $U_{j} = V_{j}$."

I'm pretty sure I understand the individual concepts, but I'm really struggling to put them together into a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $j$. Let $y \in V_j$. Then we can write $y =\sum x_i$ with $x_i \in U_i$ for all $i$. Note that $x_i \in V_i$ for all $i$. Another decomposition of $y$ as sum of elements of $V_i$'s is $0+0+...+y+0+...$ where $y$ is in the $j-$th place. By uniqueness we get $y=x_j$ Hence $y \in U_j$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @KaboMurphy Thanks. I assumed that X was finite dimensional, but probably shouldn't have. Why can we write y as a sum of x terms?

Comment: @FMcA Any vector in $X$ can be written as a sum of that type because it is given that $X$ is the sum of $X_i$'s.

Comment: And we can take that step here because the question assumes that X is the direct sum of the $U_{i}$s? Is that a reasonable way to think of it?